# «Работы по прокладке» или «работы по прокладки»?

Tags: склонение, окончания

Как правильно, и почему?

*Работы по прокладке телефонной канализации*
или
*работы по прокладки телефонной канализации?*

Answer (score 3):

В толковом словаре Дмитриева:
[рабо́та](https://endic.ru/dmytriev/Rabota-3683.html)
**12.** Работами называют трудоёмкую коллективную деятельность по сооружению, обработке чего-либо и т. д. *Начались строительные работы **по возведению** современного спортивного комплекса.*

Предлог [ПО](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE) (*кому-чему*) употребляется с дательным падежом.
[Прокла́дка](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) (ж. р., ед. ч.; = *прокладывание*) — в дательном падеже правильно писать *прокладк**е***.

Слева перегон обрывался: там был то ли завал, то ли в том самом месте **работы по прокладке** путей почему-то прекратили. [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]

Оставшиеся **работы по прокладке** делятся на шесть равных частей. [Н. А. Островский. Как закалялась сталь (1930-1934)]

Comment: Простите, но ваши ответы порой напоминают мне статьи из интернета, которые пишутся так, чтобы ответ был в самом конце и читателю пришлось перейти на сайт и дольше там пробыть :) Ты забиваешь вопрос: сколько варить гречку? А статья на сайте тебе начинает: "Сколько варить гречку? Этим вопросом задавались ещё в двухтысячном году до Н. Э. древние греки дорийского племени, когда на южных островах Эгейского моря начали культивировать завезённую из районов нынешней Северной Индии гречиху — это поистине достояние всей Ойкумены..."

Comment: И Вы, *Nektoid*, простите, что я ничего не поняла из вашей тирады. Но — искренне! — спасибо за обширнейшую *работу по варке* гречки.

Answer (score 0):

**Работы по прокладке телефонной канализации.**

Работы по кому-чему? — по прокладк*е*.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133790/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid-------).

Comment: Пример: *По чему он получил двойку?* Мне не нравится "по чему", потому что оно созвучно "почему". Может, поэтому в некоторых регионах говорят иначе.